# Firebird - database file shutdown error message

Tags: firebird, corrupt

I have a problem with my Firebird database. The primary key of one of the tables is referenced by another table that was actually dropped earlier. So this reference from a non-existent table was causing errors when I try to make any changes in the table data.

So I did a backup and restore and the bad reference was gone but now when I try to connect to my database more than once at the same time I get the following error:

> database [file path] shutdown

How can I solve this?

Comment: Was the table with the foreign key dropped: if so, that shouldn't lead to problems, or was the table with the primary key dropped: is so, that shouldn't have been possible.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not quite understand what you mean but I will try to drop and recreate the table with orphan reference, I think that would solve it.

Comment: It was a question: I can't tell from your description which table was dropped (the one containing the foreign key or the one containing the primary key). But in any case: that shouldn't cause issues and if it did it could point to a bug in Firebird.

Comment: the one containing the foreign key was dropped and any edit to the other table lead to "BLR" error. I will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your database (file, not server) has been shutdown, so Firebird does not accept connections for this database until it has been brought online again using `gfix`.

The command is:

```
gfix -online <path-to-your-database>
```

See [Database Startup and Shutdown](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html#gfix-dbstartstop) in the [Firebird Database Housekeeping Utility manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html)

Comment: In addition to that solution I had to extract SQL, remove the orphan reference and create the db again....thanks Mark

Comment: Is there same way how to do it if database prevents SYSDBA login by containing role with name "SYSDBA"? Usualy I have to use owner user, but if database is shutdowned, SYSDBA is required...

Comment: @Honza The only other option I know of is the database owner (if that is other than SYSDBA), as far as I know gfix doesn't support the `RDB$ADMIN` roles.

Comment: **Update:** I has founded solution already: `gfix -online` require SYSDBA **OR** user who shutdowned the database - if I restore database as user `test` (for example), user `test` can also `gfix -online` :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

use online

```
gfix  -user "SYSDBA" -password "masterkey"  -online DATA.FDB
```

after database is used retry

```
gfix  -user "SYSDBA" -password "masterkey"   -shut -force 0 DATA.FDB
```